# nodejs, docker, nginx and amazon aws deployment

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, docker

There have been many questions regarding docker, node and amazon aws and I have read most of them but I haven't got my answer.

I have been working on a production node.js API project for last some weeks and now that the API's are complete I have to deploy them.
There are a total of 2 microservices (this may increase later) and some worker processes. Different components of the system will communicate with each other using SQS and SNS. Each of the microservices uses mongo DB as the nosql storage and mongoose as the ODM. I chose mongolab as the mongoDB hosting provider. Currently I can connect to mongolab DB using MONGOLAB_URI environment variable (obviously this will not be enough during production any suggestion on this one is welcome)

I am going ahead with amazon aws platform.

My thought process is:

I will docerize each of the components. For worker processes it is straight forward.
For microservices I will have 2 docker images which I will deploy using amazon EC2 container service. I will have a third nginx docker image which I will put in front of node applications.

I am planning to create a cluster of 2 machines (c2 large) initially and host these 3 dockerized microservices and nginx images on these machines.
Obviously the node process will run on some port. Lets assume it to be 3100

Till now it is perfectly clear the problem came when I want to exposes these API's to outer world

The microservices exposes some endpoints like

```
service 1:- /users, /login, /me etc
service 2: /offers, /gifts etc
```

My Question is:

I want to resolve

```
mydomain.com/api/v1/users to service1:3100/users
```

similarly for other API's

I assume this can be done by nginx but I am not much familiar with it.

The constraints are:

```
I don't want to host each of the microservice on a separate machine (budget constraint).
I don't know which service will run on which machine (this I assume since I read that ec2 container service will automatically start docker processes on random machines and distribute load).
```

How Can I do this ?

Comment: Can you give some more detail about what your question is? Are you asking about Nginx? About your architecture? About ECS?

Comment: My Question is after the statement "I want to resolve.."